# held-out data and k-fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have learnt about holding some data out of the training set (development data for tuning model's parameters) and also k-fold cross validation. I got a question about them, Can we use them in all of the machine learning algorithms such as Decision Tree and Naïve Bayes?or there is restriction in using them? Is it better to use them in Decision Tree and Naïve Bayes rather than their pure algorithms in order to gain better results?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what are "their pure algorithms"???

Comment: I mean the simple algorithms without these stuff.

Comment: You are still making no sense (your question, too); what is "these stuff"??

Comment: It refers to development data and k-fold cross validation :\

Comment: I can read, but this doesn't mean what I read (i.e. what you have written) makes sense; I know of training data, validation data, test data etc, but not of "development data"... So, "these stuff" refers to dev data and k-fold CV, and you imagine that there are some "pure algos", simpler than DT & NB, without "these stuff". It is apparent that you are not actually keen to receive any help here, good luck...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could use them in all machine learning algorithms. The approach is to test how best your learning algorithm can generalize and perform on an unseen dataset.